# Communication link failure: Google Cloud Function app can't connect to Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-functions, spring-cloud-function

## Problem statement

A Java Spring Cloud Functions application deployed to Google Cloud Function instance doesn't recognize a database setup on Google Cloud SQL instance. Deploying the application to Cloud Function service using:

```
gcloud alpha functions deploy function-sample-gcp-background  \
--entry-point org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher \
--runtime java17 \
--trigger-topic  example-functions-app \
--source target/deploy \
--memory 512MB \
--region europe-central2
```

returns error in cloud function instance log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not construct an instance of org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.forClass(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:125)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.forClass(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker.startServer(Invoker.java:304)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker.startServer(Invoker.java:241)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.forClass(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:122)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher.<init>(GcfJarLauncher.java:48)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.init(FunctionInvoker.java:97)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:80)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:272)
```

some further runtime spring boot logs:

```
[function-sample-gcp-background] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[function-sample-gcp-background] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar!/:5.3.26]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar!/:2.7.10]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar!/:2.7.10]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar!/:2.7.10]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.init(FunctionInvoker.java:97) ~[spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp-4.0.1.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp-4.0.1.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp-4.0.1.jar!/:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher.<init>(GcfJarLauncher.java:48) ~[video-stream-function-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.forClass(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:122) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.forClass(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:115) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker.startServer(Invoker.java:304) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker.startServer(Invoker.java:241) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:124) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[function-sample-gcp-background] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
[function-sample-gcp-background] at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
```

**How do I manage this issue where I can't connect the database that is setup on Google Cloud SQL instance with Cloud Function instance?**

## Relevant Data

[image: GCloud Service Infrastracture Diagram showing connection between instances]
The Diagram above shows infrastracture of a google cloud setup of a Spring Cloud Functions application.
The application has an sql database setup with jpa implementation, the configuration is stored in application.yml as followed:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: username
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://99.999.999.9/db-name

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    default:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          bytecode:
            provider: none
  cloud:
    gcp:
      sql:
        instance-connection-name: instance-connection-name
        database-name: db-name
      config:
        credentials:
          location: service-account-ceredntials.json
```

For the purpose of anonymity I renamed values of above configurations.
service-account-credentials.json contain service-account key. That service account has roles of:

```
Cloud Functions Developer
Cloud SQL Editor
```

### Important Note

When the Spring Cloud Function application is run on localhost, the application is able to connect to the database on Cloud SQL using SQL instance's public IP address. The issue occurs when the Spring Cloud Function application is being deployed to Google Cloud.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is due to connection difficulties? What does `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set` mean to you?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but in Spring Boot Hibernate can determine the correct dialect to use automatically, but in order to do this, it needs a live connection to the database. When the Spring Cloud Function application is run on localhost, the application is able to connect to the database on Cloud SQL using SQL instance's public IP address. The issue occurs when the Spring Cloud Function application is being deployed to Google Cloud.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/debugging-connectivity

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki for everyone's visibility.

As mentioned by the OP, Spring Boot Hibernate can determine the correct dialect to use automatically, but it needs a live connection to the database. Since the issue is non-existent when running locally. You can try to debug your connectivity with [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/debugging-connectivity).